# Validate if the encrypted data is not tampered

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, encryption, rncryptor

I have a string encrypted using RNCryptor v2.2 ObjectiveC library.
After encryption it is stored locally on iPhone.

When want to get the string back, before decryption, I want to make sure that the encrypted is not tampered (like manually changed a character).

How can I verify this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The theoretically correct answer to your question is that whatever you do in your app locally on the device, you *will not* be more sure whether your data has been tampered or not compared to doing nothing. You will need to use an external, reliable agent such as a https web server to store some information about your data.

Let me explain this briefly. iOS already gives sufficient protection to the data of your app with its [data sandboxing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html) model assuming that the device of the user in not jailbroken. This means that there is no way to alter the private data of your app (saved in the standard Documents, Caches, etc. folder of your app). On the other hand a malicious user who wants to modify the encrypted information stored in the private folder of your app, can jailbreak the device. In this case he will have access to everything and can read and write any private folders.

Some could say that you can create a hash or a digital signature of your data and store it on the device. But if the device if jailbroken the intruder would have access to everything, including the binary code of your app (Objective-C can be reverse engineered without too much effort) and so the hash generating algorithm, the [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) or the private key of your digital signature. So he could easily manipulate the digital signature or the hash as well.

You should evaluate the risk of your data being tampered. How much effort worth tampering your data? If you are storing banking information and count about 1 million of users, you should take seriously the risk that somebody could jailbreak the device, reverse engineer your app and tamper your data. If you are storing session tokens of a photo-sharing app, maybe you can just leave it as it is and trust in the sandboxing of iOS. Also it is very important that jailbreaking the device needs active participance of the user so it is not possible to do it remotely, without the consent of the user. This means that the data can not be tampered without the consent of the user.

If you really need to protect your data then the only way is to use an external service that you trust and that can provide your an external security regarding to the device. You could send your sensitive data to a web server through https, let the web server sign it with its private key and resend to you the signature that you can store calmly wherever you want. Every time you need to access to your sensitive data you could verify the signature of the data (and the validity of the signature with the public certificate of the server). As the private key is stored on the remote server, you can be sure that nobody can access it and it can not be used to sign a tampered data.

Answer (score 0):

RNCryptor includes an HMAC to detect this. If the ciphertext is modified, it will not decrypt. You'll get an error ("HMAC Mismatch").

Comment: Same error is received even when the encrypted data is correct but password is incorrect. So when error "HMAC Mismatch" is received, how to identify whether (1) encrypted data was tampered OR (2) password was incorrect.

Comment: There is no mechanism to distinguish these cases in the v3 format. The v4 format will include a password validator. https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/draft-RNCryptor-Spec-v4.0.md

Comment: Thanks for the info Rob! When can we expect it to be available for use?

Comment: Hopefully this winter.